# Error ModuleNotFoundError con Python Wheel y Databricks

Tags: python, packages, databricks

Estoy probando ejecutar un Wheel de Python desde un job de Databricks. Todo me bien menos cuando intento llamar una clase o función que tengo en una subcarpeta del proyecto.

La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que me devuelve Databricks es el siguiente:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_code'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)    
    166 thread_local._nest_level += 1    
    168 try:    
    169     # Import the desired module. If you’re seeing this while debugging a failed import,    
    170     # look at preceding stack frames for relevant error information. 
    --> 171     original_result = python_builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)    
    173     is_root_import = thread_local._nest_level == 1    
    174     # `level` represents the number of leading dots in a relative import statement.    
    175     # If it's zero, then this is an absolute import. 

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_code'
```

Mi setup.py es:

```
import setuptools
import test_calcular
setuptools.setup(
    name='test_calcular',
    version= test_calcular.__version__,
    author= test_calcular.__autor__,
    description= "Prueba sobre empaquetar Python en Databricks",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'group_1': 'run=test_calcular.__main__:main'
    },
    install_requires=[
        'setuptools'
    ]
)
```

He leído otros post con problemas similares, pero no he logrado solucionarlo, ¿alguna idea sobre la solución?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientación hacia la solución.